# Split string into two columns with delimiter ->

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following given string to split into two columns with given `From` and `To` format.

Given string:

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(MAX) = 'A->B->C->D'
```

**Expected Result**:

```
From    To
-----------
A       B
B       C
C       D
```

Tried:

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(MAX) = 'A->B->C->D' 
SELECT CASE WHEN item LIKE '%-' THEN REPLACE(item,'-','') END AS [From],
       CASE WHEN item NOT LIKE '%-' THEN item END AS [To]   
FROM dbo.f_Split(@String,'>')
```

Comment: Does `dbo.f_Split` UDF return the positions of the splitted substrings?

Comment: @Zhorov, Yes it will return `ID`(Identity column) and `Name` of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(MAX) = 'A->B->C->D';


DECLARE @StringXML XML = CAST('<a>' + REPLACE(@String, '->', '</a><a>') + '</a>' AS XML);


WITH DataSource ([RowID], [RowValue]) AS
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.c ASC)
           ,T.c.value('.', 'CHAR(1)')
    FROM @StringXML.nodes('a') T(c)
)
SELECT DS1.[RowValue] AS [From]
      ,DS2.[RowValue] AS [TO]
FROM DataSource DS1
INNER JOIN DataSource DS2
    ON DS1.[RowID] + 1 = DS2.[RowID];
```

The idea is to split the values and order them. Then just perform join to the final row set to itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can `REPLACE` the string before processing it and directly apply joins to get the expected output. Considering the `dbo.f_Split` function returns column `item`.

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(MAX) = 'A->B->C->D->E->F->G';

SET @String = REPLACE(@String, '->', '>')

WITH CTE(RowNumber, RowData) AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY S1.item) AS RowNumber,
        S1.item AS RowData
    FROM dbo.f_Split(@String,'>') S1
)
SELECT
    C1.RowData AS [From], 
    C2.RowData AS [To]
FROM CTE C1
INNER JOIN CTE C2 ON C1.RowNumber + 1 = C2.RowNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

One more solution using the position and `+1`:

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(MAX) = 'A->B->C->D->E';

DECLARE @YourStringAsXml XML=CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(@String, '->', '</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML);
```

--the query

```sql
WITH tally(nr) AS 
(
    SELECT TOP (@YourStringAsXml.value('count(/x)','int')) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM master..spt_values
)
SELECT @YourStringAsXml.value('/x[sql:column("nr")][1]','varchar(10)') AS FromNode
      ,@YourStringAsXml.value('/x[sql:column("nr")+1][1]','varchar(10)') AS ToNode
FROM tally;
```

The idea in short:

- We transform the string to an XML
- We use a *tally-on-the-fly* with a computed `TOP()` clause to get a list of running numbers (better was - and very handsome anyway - a pyhsical numbers table).
- Now we can pick the elements by their position (`sql:column()`) and the neighbour by simply adding +1 to this position